# Set a variable in session in twig symfony 2

Tags: symfony, session, twig, session-variables

Does it exist a method to ***define*** (not to get) a session variable in twig file ?
Like this:

```
{{ app.session.set('key', value) }}
```

Comment: app.session.has ('key')

Comment: Why do you want to modify an application state from templates?

Comment: Create custom [extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) for twig that does the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Symfony 3 you can.

```
{{ app.session.set('test', 1) }}
{{ dump(app.session.get('test')) }}
```

Comment: you can, but you shouldn't modify session from a template :]

Comment: can you, please, explain why?

Comment: @HoussemZitoun because business logic should never be implemented in templates. Templates should only have data to display and that it. In future, if someone wanted to change the template, then he does not have to worry about your business logic inside the template

Comment: @Basit it's true, but lets say you have some modal to show only at login. This modal is rendered within the template (base.html.twig). You will, on successful login set a session variable to display that modal (can show on any url). How do you intend to prevent it from showing again on next link if you don't use twig in this case? You can't know where the user will land after first login (if he used a link in a mail for example) and can't know where he will go. Thus, you use twig to change the session var. You're right, but there are some special cases... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actualy nope, you can not set a session variable in twig, but you can easily add it in the controller:

```
public function someAction()
{
    // In a controller
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->set('filter', array(
      'accounts' => 'value',
    ));
}
// In Twig
{% set filter = app.session.get('filter') %}
{% set account-filter = filter['accounts'] %}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can't do this by default, but nothing stops OP from extending twig with a custom extension that could set the session for him

Comment: Agree, but to think carefully why would you need twig, to set something into session, any way it is compiled on server side.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3 you can set or update session.

```
{{ app.session.set('test', 'Apple') }}
{{ app.session.get('test') }} // return Apple

{{ app.session.set('test', 'Apple') }}
{{ app.session.set('test', 'Strawberry') }}
{{ app.session.get('test') }} // return Strawberry
```